# for () {} in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 dialog (from '#dialog1' to '#dialog10')
When I run code, all dialog hide. But when i click '#list_vt"+i', "#dialog"+i is not open. Help me please (sorry, my english is not good)
This is code:

```html
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  for(i = 1; i<=10; i++){
   $( "#dialog"+i ).dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 500
     },
     hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 500
     },
     position: { 
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left',
    of: $('#list_vt'+i)
     },
    width: 550 
   });
   $("#list_vt"+i).click(function() {
   $("#dialog"+i).dialog("open");
   })
  }
 });
```

Comment: did you try to explicitly write the name of the click function for the items like

$("#list_vt1").click(...
$("#list_vt2").click(...

Comment: when I write $("#list_vt"+1).click(function() {
   $("#dialog"+1).dialog("open");
   })

Comment: when I write $("#list_vt1").click(function() {
   $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
   }) dialog1 open. But i must write 10 paragraph, it is very long. i don't like it